# Get Image Click from ImageGetter in Android

Tags: android, image, getter

I am using `ImageGetter` to display Images and Texts in `TextView`. It is working fine. Now, issue is that our some data contains `Equation` images and `ImageGetter` is showing it very small Image which can't be easily visible to User.
I have also tried setting `bounds` but as I check some data, It may vary image to image so It is not proper solution for me.
So, now I have planned to put `Click` event on Image and get `src` of Image which is displaying in `ImageGetter`. how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add images and text in a view group i.e linear layout. And set click listener on that linear layout.

Comment: I can use `TextView onClickListener()` but I want specific click event of `Image` and that `Image src`.

Comment: Take imageview and textview in a linearlayout. And apply clicklistner on imageview. Dont use imagegetter on textview.try to set image in imageview.